# Unable to install pecl imagick

Tags: php, pecl

Environment:

- CentOS 6.8
- PHP 5.6.5 (installed via Software Collections)

I'm getting the following error when trying to install imagick:

```
[root@vm ~]# pecl install imagick
No releases for package "pecl/imagick" exist
install failed
```

I'm able to successfully install other extensions perfectly fine, except for imagick. I've already tried updating all channels/purged cache and still no luck.

A strange thing is that I'm able to view the extension, but it won't show the "Latest" version of it.

```
[root@vm ~]# pecl remote-info imagick
Package details:
================
Latest
Installed   - no -
Package     imagick
License     PHP License
Category    Images
Summary     Provides a wrapper to the ImageMagick library.
Description Imagick is a native php extension to create and
            modify images using the ImageMagick API.
            This extension requires ImageMagick version
            6.5.3-10+ and PHP 5.4.0+.
```

Any one have any ideas on why I can't install the imagick extension? This wasn't a problem a few months ago.

Comment: Why don't you install it from your Software Collection then? On my local CentOS mirror I see the package named `sclo-php56-php-pecl-imagick`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I wasn't able to originally see the `sclo-php56-php-pecl-imagick` package because my system was configured to only grab the RH maintained packages (centos-release-scl-rh). I enabled centos-release-scl so I can grab `sclo-php56-php-pecl-imagick`